# Get the Xcode File of My App Installed on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am really scared because when I run my app on my simulator, it just crashes. I am not looking for help with the crash. I have a working version installed onto my iPhone. I am wondering: is there **any** possible way to grab the Xcode file from my iPhone and use that instead of the current one?

I am really scared that my app no longer works.

Thanks!

Comment: No,you cannot. The app running on your iphone is .ipa file,it is compiled binary code and relative resources. If you want roll back to original version,you need use version control tools like git during your programming progress.

Answer (score 0):

The file on your phone isn't "an Xcode file", it's a compiled binary app file. This unfortunately cannot be transformed back into source code that could be opened by Xcode.

How and when was the version on your phone built? Hopefully you have your code checked into a version control system and can revert to the version that was used to build the app currently on your phone.